# Как сохранить данные в Python в txt файле?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Вот часть кода. Подскажите, как сделать чтобы  приходящие ответы от сервера сохранялись в блокнот (txt)?

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.GROUP_JOIN:
        print(event.obj.user_id, end=' ')
        print()
    elif event.type == VkBotEventType.GROUP_LEAVE:
        print(event.obj.user_id, end=' ')
        print()
```

Comment: Можно перенаправить весь `stdout` скрипта в файл. `python script.py > file.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У функции `print()` есть параметр для этого:

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
    print(event.obj.user_id, end=' ', file=f)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.